# I am getting access denied error on saving bean shell assertion in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

I have started leaning JMeter. So, this one tutorial asked to save the Bean Shell Assertion. On trying to save it, I am getting Access Denied error.

[image]

Comment: Any feedback on answer ? If ok you should accept it and upvote so that others can trust it ?

Answer (score 0):

Your user has not right to write in this folder.

Change to your user's Documents folder

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to save file under the [Program Files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Files) folder you need to be an [Administrator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923/windows-10-create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account) of your machine.

Another option is [running JMeter as an Administrator](https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-run-programs-administrator-windows-7):

[image]

Or alternatively you can grant to your user account `Full control` rights onto JMeter folder:

[image]

---

In general overall quality of the guide can be a big question mark as:

1. [Assertion will not be executed if there is no Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#executionorder)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting as:

   - Groovy scripts can be compiled and cached - it greatly improves script performance
   - Groovy engine is faster than Beanshell per se
   - Groovy is more "modern" language and it supports all underlying Java features while in Beanshell you're stuck at Java 5 language level and cannot use generics, streams, lambdas, etc.
   - On top of this Groovy has a [lot of enhancements](http://groovy-lang.org/gdk.html), for instance [built-in JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html) support

If above points are enough to convince you - check out [Scripting JMeter Assertions in Groovy - A Tutorial](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial) article.